# Windows equivalent of su

Tags: windows, su

During start up, Group Policy can be used to run scripts before user log in. These scripts run as the local system account, which I understand to be effectively like root. I'd like to run a script as a lesser user, so I was looking for a `su` equivalent for Windows. I've tried `runas` but even when invoked as the local system account, it still requests the lesser user's password. In *nix, running `su` as root doesn't require a password (root always has permission)

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking.  You describe as wanting to run as a user with less privileges than administrator but have a problem with being asked for a password.  That all sounds consistent to me.  What am I missing?

Comment: @fixer1234 In a *nix environment, if you are running as root you can switch to any user you want. No password is required. A common paradigm is to start a service as root, let it bind to whatever privileged ports it needs to, and then let it fork itself as a user with lesser privilege. This transition from high privilege (root) to low privilege (other user) doesn't require any credentials as root has permission to do whatever it wants.

Comment: In that sense, run as administrator isn't quite the same as SU.  Windows has a "super administrator" account that you have to set up as you would any user account.  However, it has the level of permissions you're talking about.  From that account, you can access anything and any user without being asked for a password.

Comment: I set it up years ago.  Here is a link to how to do it: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/activate-windows-super-administrator-account.  My recollection is that I did it a different way but can't remember what that was.  According to this, you don't necessarily need to create a user profile.  I did because I was sick of dealing with UAC every time I turned around and used it as a regular account (unsafe--don't try this at home).

Comment: @fixer1234 No dice. Even as the administrator user (rather than a user acting as an administrator) I am still prompted for a password when using `runas` and `psexec`

Comment: At what part are you being asked for password; at the "runas" or for the "psexec"? The runas may be completing fine but psexec is normally to run something on a remote computer and this may ask for authentication... hence the prompt for password...

Comment: My recollection is that as super administrator, you don't need runas.  You already have permission to do anything in any account.  I don't recall having to enter a password for anything after login.

Comment: @BigChris I should have said "runas" OR "psexec", meaning I tried each on their own and both prompted for a password to execute a program on this computer as a different user (when running as the 'administrator' user).

Comment: @fixer1234 I don't want to execute a program as the administrator, I want to execute it as a different user. That's the whole point. The transition to another user is requiring the other users password, even when running as the 'administrator' user.

Comment: If you run a program as the super administrator, you don't need a password for anything or any user.  You can access files or programs of another user, but you can't run things **as** them.  If you want to run a program **as** another regular user, you need a password.  That's the same as in Linux.  You can be only one user at a time.

Comment: @fixer1234 _If you want to run a program as another reguler user,  you need a password. That's the same as in Linux._ Not true. As root on Linux, I can use 'su' to execute any prorgram as any user **without** a password. I'm having the exact same problem as OP: I know the admin password on the Windows machine and I need to do something as a regular user, for which I don't know the password and I don't want to reset it either. I can't imagine a hundred million system administrators ran into this problem before...

Comment: @JvO, I had forgotten about this thread.  Yeah, I'm not an IT guy; my understanding of these issues is spotty and I was pretty new to Linux at the time of this post.  The more I learn, the less I know.  :-)  I thought I was helping, but since then, I realize how much I was misinformed.  This question never attracted an answer and I think Huckle just gave up on it.  If you have a similar situation, consider posting a new question.  If yours is able to attract an answer, we can always link this as a duplicate.